# inotifywait different action on file or dir

Tags: bash, ubuntu, files, directory, inotify

I'm trying to make a `inotifywait` script take different actions for files vs folders if it sees a close_write flag being raised in the watched directory, but cannot seem to get the checks working.

In other scripts I use these kinds of checks all the time and they just_work, but there seems to be something about `inotifywait` I'm not grasping yet.

This is the script in its current form:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    dir1=/sambashares

    while true; do
     inotifywait -r -e close_write "$dir1" | while read f; do
      #debug
      echo $f
      #Is it a directory?
      if [[ -d "${f}" ]]; then
       #debug
       echo "New directory called ${f} detected"
       chown -R jake:jake $f
       chmod -R 775 $f
       cp -R $f /media/lacie/Film
      fi
      #Is it a file?
      if [[ -f "${f}" ]]; then 
      #debug
      echo "New file called ${f} detected"
      chown jake:jake $f
      chmod 775 $f
      cp $f /media/lacie/Film
      fi

     done
    done
```

If I run this in a terminal to see what is happening all I get is the confirmation a close_write was detected, followed by a "setting up watches" without any other messages or any of the other code being triggered, not even the debug echo directly below:

```
 while read f; do
```

:-(

I'm running this on Ubuntu server 12.04 LTS 64 bit.

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

$ dpkg -l | grep inotify
ii  inotify-tools                    3.13-3
ii  libinotifytools0                 3.13-3
ii  python-pyinotify                 0.9.2-1

$ python --version
Python 2.7.3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works for me:

#### Example

Below shows an example of `inotifywait` using a method similar to your own.

```
$ inotifywait -r -e close_write "somedir" | while read f; do echo "$f hi";done
Setting up watches.  Beware: since -r was given, this may take a while!
Watches established.
```

I then go into the directory `somedir` and touch afile, `touch afile`. Which results in this occurring in the `inotifywait` window:

```
somedir/ CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE afile hi
```

**NOTE:** To get all the output from `inotifywait` you could modify your example slightly:

```
$ inotifywait -r -e close_write "somedir" 2>&1 | \
    while read f; do echo "$f | hi";done
Setting up watches.  Beware: since -r was given, this may take a while! | hi
Watches established. | hi
```

And again touch a file with the command, `touch afile`, I now see the event:

```
somedir/ CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE afile | hi
```

For another example that shows how to use `inotifywait` take a look at the example I showed in my answer to this Q&A titled: [Automatically detect when a file has reached a size limit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132054/automatically-detect-when-a-file-has-reached-a-size-limit/).

#### Your issue

I believe part of your issue is that you're assuming that the output returned from `inotifywait` is just the file's name while clearly it isn't from the above examples.

So these `if` statements will never succeed:

```
  if [[ -d "${f}" ]]; then

and

  if [[ -f "${f}" ]]; then
```

When developing Bash scripts such as this it's often helpful to enable debugging messages via this command at the top:

```
set -x
```

You can disable it with this:

```
set +x
```

You can wrap sections of your code using these messages to turn it on/off.

```
set -x
...code...
set +x
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the debug option in bash, i did not know about this and it will help me a lot in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Got it working thanks to the info slm provided :-)

```
#!/bin/bash

# Written by Jan Duprez and licensed as
# do whatever you want with this but don't come whining
# if you somehow manage to trash your system with it.
# You pressed the buttons, remember?

# This script uses inotifywait to watch a directory and copies
# files or directories moved into it to another folder.

# The commandline parameters are:
# 1 - Directory to watch
# 2 - Directory where new file/folder is copied to
# 3 - UID to use to chmod the file/folder in BOTH dirs
# 4 - GID to use to chmod the file/folder in BOTH dirs
# 5 - permissions to set for the new file/folder in BOTH dirs

dir1=$1
dir2=$2
user=$3
group=$4
perms=$5

# Check if commandline parameters are all there, show reminder if not
if [[ -z $dir1 || -z $dir2 || -z $user || -z $group || -z $perms ]];
then    
    echo -e "Please provide a source dir as 1st parameter"
            echo -e "Please provide a dest dir as 2nd parameter"
            echo -e "Please provide a UID as 3rd parameter"
            echo -e "Please provide a GID as 4th parameter"
            echo -e "Please provide a file permission string (ex 755) as 5th parameter"
    exit
fi

# Good to go, start watching
while true; do

#add -e close_write and -e create for testing
inotifywait -r -e move "$dir1" | while read f; do

#Get part after inotify triggers with awk, remove leading spaces with sed
new=`echo $f | awk '{$1=$2=""; print $0}' | sed 's/^ *//'`
#And the preconstruded full path to avoid ugly buggery between the  [[ ]]    test
test=$dir1$new

    if [[ -d "${test}" ]] ; then
    chown -R $user:$group "$dir1$new"
    chmod -R $perms "$dir1$new"
    cp -R "$dir1$new" "$dir2"
    chown -R $user:$group "$dir2$new"
    fi

    if [[ -f "${test}" ]] ; then
    chown $user:$group "$dir1$new"
    chmod $perms "$dir1$new"
    cp "$dir1$new" "$dir2"
    chown $user:$group "$dir2$new"
    fi
done
done
```