# How to notify if a file exceeds a certain size

Tags: linux, bash

Based on some work i found on other posts I created this script but the only response I get is "setting up watches" and "watches established"

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 3>&1 4>&2
trap 'exec 2>&4 1>&3' 0 1 2 3
exec 1>log.out 2>&1
file=/home/oracle/app/oracle/oradata/flex12c/temp02.dbf # file
maxsize=100 # 100 kilobytes

while inotifywait -e access "$file"; do
    actualsize=$(du -k "$file" | cut -f1)
    if [ $actualsize -ge $maxsize ]; then
        echo size is over $maxsize kilobytes
        subject="size exceeded on file $file"
            emailAddr="email@contoso.com"
            mailCmd="mail -s \"$subject\" \"$emailAddrs\""
        ( echo ""; echo "DATE: $(date)"; ) | eval mail -s "$subject" \"$emailAddr\"
        exit    
    else
        echo size is under $maxsize kilobytes
    fi
done
```

Comment: You'll probably want to use the `modify` event instead of `access` if you want to detect changes to file.

Comment: Check this, as it is exactly what you want:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/132113/448601